# HTTP Status Code 401 but return OK

Tags: angularjs, laravel, nginx

I'm using angular and laravel for my front and back end, respectively.

I got a problem on production, when a user goes into dashboad without login will return `401 (Unauthorized)`. But in my case `Status Code:401 OK`.

In my development it works perfectly. It always return me unauthorized.

Server: Nginx .

[image: error]

What should i change?

Thanks

Comment: Who sends 401? Nginx? Laravel?

Comment: I don't know. My development using nginx too. But it receive 401 (Unauthorized). Only on production receive 401 OK.

Comment: Try do it on postman for testing your backend API.

Comment: postman return 401 OK. I'm using cloudflare too, but it's not change it right?